# How to order angular-cli scripts

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

My `angular-cli.json` has the following:

```
...
"scripts": [
    ... 
    "../node_modules/jquery-ui/ui/widget.js",
    "../node_modules/jquery-ui/ui/widgets/datepicker.js",
    "../node_modules/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon/dist/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js",
    ...
],
...
```

At https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon/blob/master/dist/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js#L15 I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'timepicker' of undefined`. I found this is because webpack is loading the scripts in the following order:

`jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js`
`widget.js`
`datepicker.js`

`widget.js` needs to load before `jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js`. Why dose webpack not load in the same order as the configuration and how do you determine the order the files load?

Comment: I have the same problem. Still looking for a solution.

Comment: My current workaround is hard coding CDNs in the head tag of index.html for everything that has to load in a particular order.

Comment: Any success ? Did you raise an issue ?

Comment: No, and no. I haven't revisited this issue since I started using CDNs for everything jquery related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not supported at the moment (as of beta.24).

You'll probably need to open a new Github issue to maintain the scripts order as per the `angular-cli.json` configuration.

Another option you can try is importing the files from TypeScript.

Comment: Importing in typescript doesn't help me because I don't need to use these libraries directly but I'm using a library that requires these be be loaded in the global scope or namespace or window (like a script tag)

Answer (score 0):

The scripts do load in the order they are in `angular-cli.json`, the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'timepicker' of undefined` was do to `$.ui` being defined in  `jquery-ui/ui/version.js` not `jquery-ui/ui/widget.js`.

My mistake.

> ...while it does look like they are loaded in the wrong order because of the numbers, they are loaded in the right order...
>   https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3782#issuecomment-269883288